# Rating an App in Android TV

Tags: google-play-store, android-tv, app-ratings

I've been searching around for any official docs and some 3rd party sites but I can't find a way to rate an app via the Android TV itself, without installing a 3rd party browser app to browse Google Play Store.

When using the Google Play Store, selecting *My Apps* then selecting the app you want to rate, it only shows four buttons:

- <kbd>Update</kbd>
- <kbd>Uninstall</kbd>
- <kbd>Full Description</kbd>
- <kbd>Flag as Inappropriate</kbd>

I've also seen this [Hidden Android TV Browser](https://youtu.be/3_bP1-fhGfQ?t=30s) thing, maybe it'd be possible to just rate the app by using a internal browser then going to the Play Store site, but it doesn't seem to work (maybe it used to, but not anymore), it just shows:

> *Restricted Access. No browser was found.*

So I'm wondering if this is even possible? If no, is there any reason as to why they wouldn't allow users to rate an app via the Play Store when using an Android TV? Or is there any feature request for this (wasn't able to find one, maybe someone already did and I just wasn't able to find it)?

---

PS: I did try using a 3rd party browser app to rate an app by going to the Play Store site, but it's not a good experience for a user to go through all that (installing another app to go to Play Store, login again, then find the app to rate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like currently, it is not possible to rate an app via Android TV Platform. However it looks like the feature will be coming soon as mentioned in this [blog post](http://androidtv.news/2016/05/app-reviews-ratings-come-play-store/):

> **The team is working on the feature, but there isn’t an ETA.**

Credits go to @MattLane and @NickFelker for providing the information in this [post](https://plus.google.com/113957119459839778459/posts/EGoc9FM7hLb).